# Calculate daily overtime and daily mean overtime of a resourcePool - anylogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I'm trying to calculate the overtime of each resourcePool, what I reached is time-consuming and almost a manual calculation, looking for the correct way to do that, please.

What I'm doing is as follows, for example, I have the pharmacists' resource pool (regular hours, and over time pool, I divide them to be easier for me to get statistics of each shift and for optimization later on):
[image]

I added the following traceln in onExist realse of the pharmacists:

```
traceln(date());
traceln(agent.OrderID);
```

So it returns the date and time of all passed agents. Then I run the model and copy the traceln outputs from the console and process them in Excel:

```
the overtime hours of the day = last recorded time of a certain date - the start of overtime shift
```

I repeat the above for each day which takes too much time, especially since there are other resources that also I need their overtime.

Is there any simplified and quick method to get the daily overtime (and the daily mean overtime) of a resourcePool?

Thank you.